# How do you fix a "failed to start dhcpcd on all interfaces" error?

Tags: boot

i've never had this error since i bought my rpi3 last january. Any advice?

**Details**:

**OS**: **Raspbian Stretch**

Never edited /etc/network/interfaces as pi is attached to router via cable and had not needed to use wi-fi

**journalctl -e** (errors found)

```
vc_vhci_sm_init: failed to open VCHI service (-1)
[vc_sm_connected_init]: failed to initialize shared memory service

brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: CLM version = API: 12.2 Data: 7.11.15 Compiler: 1.24.2 ClmImport: 1.24.1 Creation: 2014-05-26 10:53:55 Inc Data: 9.10.41 Inc Compiler: 1.29.4 Inc ClmImport: 1.36.3 Creation: 2017-08-07 00:37:47

sd 0:0:0:0 [sda] No Caching mode page found
sd 0:0:0:0 [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through

dhcpcd.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/lib/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd: Exec format error

dhcpcd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
Failed to start dhcpcd on all interfaces
dhcpcd.service: Unit entered failed state
dhcpcd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

Comment: What OS + version do you run? Did you modify /etc/network/interfaces? Please add that information to your question.

Comment: Currently version is stretch and no modifications made to interfaces. Just used network cable to router from the beginning and thats it. This just happened today so I'm very confused.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output from `ip addr`. That will give an overview about the status of your interfaces. Look at `journalctl -e` for any error messages.

Comment: Updated with results from ip addr and errors from journalctl -e

Comment: Odd error starting dhcpcd5 (Exec format error). What does 'file' report on that file (should be a script)? Also 'file /sbin/dhcpcd'

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: would it be quicker if i just reformat my sd card?

Comment: yes, it would be quicker

Comment: @Kurover: Before you reformat, please run this, and report result `journalctl -u dhcpcd.service`

Comment: Also: This is worth asking [Roy Marples](https://roy.marples.name/) a question... but I think his mail list server is having issues at the moment, so you may need to wait a bit.

Comment: unfortunately I've already reformatted the sd card.

Answer (score 4):

For those googlin' `"failed to start dhcpcd on all interfaces"` like myself:

- *NB: This is relevant to Raspbian Stretch; for a different release, the situation may differ.*

Essentially, if your Pi has a wired DHCP connection, and you have eth0 in `/etc/network/interfaces` -- something like that :

```
# .. loopback interface ..
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Then it shall be enough and you can now disable `dhcpcd.service` :

```
systemctl disable dhcpcd
```

This shall be it -- reboot ( and don't forget to start your DCHP server, if your client is dhcp-bound ) and you shall not have this message for anymore.

---

Explanation: I suppose we have triggered `dhcpcd.service` into an `enabled` state, and since its `Description` field is *"dhcpcd on all interfaces"* -- it goes into the log file as "failed to start *dhcpcd on all interfaces*" . That's it.

---

- Edit: fixed typos, thanks Ingo

Comment: Seems you have done some typos. There is no *dhcpd* service you can disable. Do you mean *dhcp**c**d*?

Comment: @Ingo : thanks, it did not occur to me it has a 'c' there. I mean, I did it just not too long ago, but nevertheless did some typing mistakes here. Thanks again )

Comment: Of course -- my bad. It is a *client*, therefore it shall go with a 'c'.