# Can't connect to Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, micropython

I am trying to connect to an Raspberry Pi Pico from an Raspberry Pi 3B+ running Raspian Bullseye. The Pico shows up in the File Manager when I connect with the BOOTSEL button pressed. When I try to install the MicroPython interpreter via the Thonny Interpreter Configuration dialogue it appears to work. I get the 'Done!' message and looking at the dialogue that appears when you click Done I see the following:

```
Waiting for the port
Found 2e8a:0005 at /dev/ttyACM0
Done!
```

That seems to indicate that the firmware install worked, but I don't see any REPL prompt in Thonny and I get:

```
Backend terminated or disconnected. Use 'Stop/Restart' to restart.
```

But 'Stop/Restart' doesn't do anything, nor do any of the other Thonny commands.

I have tried to flash both the `MicroPython_RenameMainDotPy.uf2` file and the `flash_nuke.uf2` file, but neither makes any difference, and I typically get an error saying `An operation is already pending` and I haven't found any way to clear this seemingly blocked operation.

I have tried two Picos, with the same results for both. Both Picos were working fine a few months ago, and the only thing I have done in the meantime is an `apt update` followed by an `apt upgrade`. Apt tells me that Thonny is the latest version when I try to upgrade it.

**UPDATE:** The above is incorrect, I did upgrade from Raspbian Buster to Bullseye some months ago on the Raspberry Pi host. That may well have something to do with it. I had forgotten that.

I also thought it might be a bad USB cable, but I have tried 3 or 4 different cables with exactly the same results.

This is extremely frustrating. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

**NEW UPDATE:** I tried the Pico on an RPi 4 also running bullseye and REPL in Thonny works fine on that host after flashing the MicroPython interpreter. The only difference between that and my RPi 3B+ is that I did an `apt update` followed by `apt upgrade` two days ago on the 3B+. It seems that quite a bit was upgraded as `connman` was installed on the 3B+, but it wasn't on the model 4B. So, something got updated/upgraded recently that is blocking proper connection with the Pico.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No internet connection post-buster to bullseye upgrade](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/133945/no-internet-connection-post-buster-to-bullseye-upgrade)

Comment: I usually do a ***swap troubleshoot***, ie, swap Rpi4 with an evil Win10 PC.  It takes less than 3 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED:** Enabling the serial port in raspbi-config resolved the problem. I can now access the Pico through the new port marked

```
    Board in FS mode - Board CDC (/dev/ttyACM0)
```

However, on my RPi 4B the serial port was not enabled and I was still able to access the `micropython` REPL prompt.