# Starting problem after Buster upgrade to Bullseye

Tags: boot-issues, raspberry-pi-os, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, raspberry-pi-os-buster, systemd-startup

I have a Raspberri Pi 4 of 4Gb my Operating System was Debian Buster that I upgraded to Bullseye and since when I restart I have a whole bunch of messages see the screenshots attached it seems to me that I I had the same problem when I upgraded to Buster that this is a file check via the package upgrade servers and that it's possible to skip these steps but I don't do not know how and or which file ?

It starts normally, lists all the processes then instead of loading the desktop it continues to start processes by displaying them askew (see screenshot) so no desktop, ssh connection, terminal.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has pasted screen shots from a terminal instead of the C&P the text in the terminal. This is hard to read, and contains insufficient information for a definitive answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No internet connection post-buster to bullseye upgrade](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/133945/no-internet-connection-post-buster-to-bullseye-upgrade)

Comment: I didn't copy paste the terminal text because I don't have a mouse it's not a screenshot of the terminal but a screenshot of my screen the raspberri starts normally but instead of loading the debian desktop it keeps loading with these processes it starts with Starting http proxy then exim mail etc...

Comment: I think it checks for new installed packages or continues to load some, I may have answered the question incorrectly:
Do you want to restart the services?
During the upgrade because I started Buster normally then changed Buster to Bullseye in the raspi.list file and sent the commands sudo apt update then full-upgrade etc then restart and there it has been milling for 48 Hours I see on my router that Internet traffic is happening but why and for how long I don't know

Comment: My version of Debian (Buster) had to install a lot of things like a PHP server, mySQL, NodeJS, NPM, Webmin, Iptable, Unbound, and other programs like SuperCollider, Sublime Text, etc. And everything was working fine before the upgrade.

Comment: For some reason, the good folks at raspberry pi incorporated basically use debian for the operating system, but, somehow, have managed to make it very fragile when upgrading between major releases ... at least, they always say "we don't support upgrading from x to y release"

Comment: @JaromandaX the "reason" is simple and well documented. They simply don't have the staff and resources to test the possible permutations. Expert users CAN upgrade BUT most do so immediately. Waiting 18 months to "upgrade" just makes the task more difficult (even for expert users). In fact the issues are recognised and Buster CONTINUES to be supported.

Comment: @JaromandaX the "problems" commonly experienced have NOTHING to do with Bullseye but the other major changes in Raspberry Pi OS .

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer but I reinstalled everything, now everything works.